# Sending Data from HTML to Servlet by two different methods

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, servlets

I've been sending data from HTML to my servlet like this :

```
<form Action="http://caregap2.appspot.com/src.main.java.org.deri.hcls.caregap2.client" Method="GET">
Username: <input type="text" name="username" size="20" value="@gmail">
<BR>
<input type="submit" VALUE="submit">
<input type="reset" value="reset">
</form>
```

which sends the variable Username to the servlet. But I don't want to have click submit to send the data, I would like to just post the data and load the servlet without clicking anything. I've tried this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var username = "foo@example.com";
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://caregap2.appspot.com/src.main.java.org.deri.hcls.caregap2.client",
      data: { username: "username" }
    }).done(function( msg ) {
     // alert( "Data Saved: " + username );
      window.location = "http://caregap2.appspot.com/src.main.java.org.deri.hcls.caregap2.client?q=" + username;
    });
});
```

But it doesn't work, can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?? Or if I should use a different method? Help would be really appreciated!! :)

Here's my servlet method :

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html");{
        ServletOutputStream  out = response.getOutputStream();
        try {
            out.println("<html><head><title>" +  "</title></head>");
            out.println("<body><h1>" +  "</h1>");
            String  name = request.getParameter("username" );
            //String  comment = request.getParameter( "comment" );
            out.println("Name:" + name + "<BR>");
            //out.println("Comment: " + comment + "<BR>");
        }
        catch(Throwable  t ) {
            out.println("<P><pre>");
            t.printStackTrace( new PrintStream(out) );
            out.println ("</pre><P>");
        }
        out.println ("</body></html>");
    }
```

Comment: What does it do? Have you tried alerting `msg` to see what it displays?

Comment: msg says "Data Saved : <html> <head> <title> </title> </head> <body> <h1> </h1> Name:username <BR> </body> </html>

Comment: Also, I wouldn't use done in Ajax as you are unaware of the state. Use Success/Failure callbacks - Or at least just use "Success" on it's own and swallow failed ajax calls.

Comment: @MattMcGrath Also you dont need the 'msg' in `}).done(function( msg ) {` if your not using MSG in the return.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I think I know what it is you are tryng to do.  AJAX requests are not what you want.  From my understanding you are trying to load a servlet and display it without havign to interact with your page at all.

All you need to do is in javascript do the following

```
var username = "you username here";
window.location = "http://caregap2.appspot.com/src.main.java.org.deri.hcls.caregap2.client?username=" + username;
```

Using an ajax request will return the servlet body to the done method, this would be useful for displaying the information on the current page without reloading.

What you are currently doing is appending the servlet response body to the end of your query and as such redirecting to the wrong place.

**Extra Info:**  The alternative using Ajax would be to get your servlet to return some html but not necesserily a full page, then use this response to populate part of your current page.

Comment: Unfortunately its still null on the server side. I've added the servlet code above to see if i have an error there

Comment: It works fine for me, did you copy and paste the code before I modified it to use `username` instead of `q` in the get parameters?

Comment: Actually ive just seen ive declared the URL wrong, ill try again

Answer (score 3):

Your JSON data is wrong:

```
data: { "username": username }
```

First the key, than the value (variable)

Comment: Thanks, but it still doesn't work. Does it have anything to do with what I'm doing with window.location? Is that the incorrect way to load the servlet?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do with the response from the ajax request?  And what exactly are you expecting the ajax request to return?

Comment: i just sort of want to see if the data is sent, its not necessary though, all I really want to do is send the variable and then load the servlet and see the value there

Comment: What you're doing right now: You have a variable named username, you send it via post to the server, after it was send, you change location.

Comment: Try to use window.location.href = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

Comment: His problem is that he is adding the body of the servlet to the GET parameters in his second query.  What he actually wants to do is redirect to the servlet without doing an ajax request as per my answer above.

Answer (score 2):

It seems your form is using a `GET` request and your ajax is performing a `POST` request.  It is probable that your service is looking for `GET` parameters.  Change the ajax request to use `GET` instead of `POST`

Comment: I tried changing POST to GET put the variable is still not getting picked up on the server side.